# Adjust CLOCK_REALTIME based timer on settimeofday

Tags: c, timer, posix

I have a POSIX timer that should fire every time 3 AM rolls around.

The obvious implementation is to use `timer_create` with `CLOCK_REALTIME`, and set the timeout to 3 AM, either today or tomorrow depending on the current time.

That works well for all cases except when the system time is corrected backwards. If the user sets the clock one year in the future and then back to the correct date, the new timer value will be set to tomorrow in one year, so the timer will not elapse for an entire year.

As a workaround, I can probably determine for each repeating timer when the previous timeout should have occurred, and if I ever see a system time before that, I correct all existing timers, however that still requires a separate wake up reason.

Is there a way to be notified if the system clock is set backwards, either in general or before a given time, or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you're overthinking this - it's 2017, a system's clock never needs to be set (rather than just drift-corrected) except at boot, and the clock should never be wrong by more than a few milliseconds (ideally microseconds), all kept in proper shape by ntp, ptp, or similar. In my book, it's perfectly acceptable to simply *document* that your software will not behave as expected under discontinuous clock adjustments.

If that's not acceptable to you, your options are limited:

- You could use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`, and set the timer without `TIMER_ABSTIME`, using the difference between 3am and the current time reported by `CLOCK_REALTIME` as the interval. This has the advantage that, even with arbitrary clock resets, you will never miss the 3am event by more than 24 hours, but you can still miss it if the time within the day is adjusted.
- Use a timer with short expiry and poll on each timer even whether you've just crossed the 3am boundary. This will never miss the event by more than your timer interval, but wastes considerable cpu resources (and prevents deep sleep) polling.

There are other variants of these methods but in terms of pros and cons they're essentially equivalent.